# How to solve gdb "warning: unhandled dyld version (17)"

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb

all.

I need to install gdb to be able to debug some fortran 90 code. However, I am running into lots of errors trying to install this on mac.

First, I got the error [24069](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24069) that I solved with the following commands. These commands also show how I built gdb:

```
 brew install --build-from-source --head domq/gdb/gdb
```

My gdb version is shown below:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 15.0.50.20231019-git
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I built some c++ code to just test the way gdb runs. This is the source code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0; 
}
```

Here is my compiler and makefile settings:

```
g++-13 (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
########################################################################
####################### Makefile Template ##############################
########################################################################
# Compiler settings - Can be customized.
CC = /usr/local/bin/g++-13
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -arch x86_64 -ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic
LDFLAGS = 

# Makefile settings - Can be customized.
APPNAME = myapp
EXT = .cpp
SRCDIR = src/include
OBJDIR = obj

############## Do not change anything from here downwards! #############
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT))
OBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEP = $(OBJ:$(OBJDIR)/%.o=%.d)
# UNIX-based OS variables & settings
RM = rm
DELOBJ = $(OBJ)
# Windows OS variables & settings
DEL = del
EXE = .exe
WDELOBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)\\%.o)

########################################################################
####################### Targets beginning here #########################
########################################################################

all: $(APPNAME)

# Builds the app
$(APPNAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Creates the dependecy rules
%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
    @$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $< -MM -MT $(@:%.d=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) >$@

# Includes all .h files
-include $(DEP)

# Building rule for .o files and its .c/.cpp in combination with all .h
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

################### Cleaning rules for Unix-based OS ###################
# Cleans complete project
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(DELOBJ) $(DEP) $(APPNAME)

# Cleans only all files with the extension .d
.PHONY: cleandep
cleandep:
    $(RM) $(DEP)

#################### Cleaning rules for Windows OS #####################
# Cleans complete project
.PHONY: cleanw
cleanw:
    $(DEL) $(WDELOBJ) $(DEP) $(APPNAME)$(EXE)

# Cleans only all files with the extension .d
.PHONY: cleandepw
cleandepw:
    $(DEL) $(DEP)
```

When I run gdb in command line, I write:

```
gdb ./myapp 
GNU gdb (GDB) 15.0.50.20231019-git
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./myapp...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/nrlmisiscpp/myapp 
[New Thread 0x2503 of process 2819]
^C[Thread 0x2503 of process 2819 exited]
[New Thread 0x3f03 of process 2819]
warning: unhandled dyld version (17)
Hello World!
[Inferior 1 (process 2819) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Notice that I need to hit ctrl+c to cause it to exit before the normal functioning proceeds.

How do I solve the warning provided?

Answer (score -2):

The 'warning: unhandled dyld version (17)' in GDB is typically related to compatibility issues between the GDB version and the current dyld version. To resolve this warning, consider updating GDB to a version that supports the specific dyld version you are using. Additionally, ensure that your system is updated with the latest patches and versions to maintain compatibility between GDB and the dynamic linker. Exploring GDB's official documentation and community forums might offer additional insights and potential solutions to address this warning effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know how I can see what dyld I have? I don't see it on my machine anywhere.